# unconstrained type parameter when implementing trait for a function

Tags: rust

Suppose I have the following trait `Trait` with an associated type `T`:

```
trait Trait {
    type T;
    fn fun(&self, x: Self::T) -> Self::T;
}
```

I can implement this trait for all functions that take no arguments and return some type `H` by giving them an implementation of `fun` that ignores its argument ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f32de3159af446e395affa050b88c9c4)):

```
impl<F: Fn() -> H, H> Trait for F {
    type T = H;
    fn fun(&self, _x: H) -> H {
        (self)()
    }
}
```

And this compiles fine. However, if I want to do the even more straightforward thing, it fails to compile. I want to implement `Trait` for all functions that take `H` and return `H` instead ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7233d7dbfd8c1305e4dbecee703a8133)):

```
impl<F: Fn(H) -> H, H> Trait for F {
    type T = H;
    fn fun(&self, x: H) -> H {
        (self)(x)
    }
}
```

And this fails to compile with:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `H` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
```

How is `H` not constrained in the failing case, while it presumably is constrained in the correct case?

Comment: Not sure this actually gives you what you're after, but if you pull the definiton of `F` out into a type alias for a trait object it [compiles fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b5f478790daec4a798c91b6f53aad0a3) I'm guessing because `H` is now constrained in the implementation of `F` in a way it isn't in your example.

Comment: I remember seeing this and digging into it... But I don't remember what were the results :P

Comment: @JaredSmith A `dyn Fn` is a completely different type, it is no surprise it compiles.

Comment: I hope it's at least obvious that you can't have _both_ implementations at once.

Comment: I meant **can't**.

Comment: Found it! Closed as duplicate.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes, hence 2 separate playgrounds:)